# Should the "seed" and "mnemonic-seed" tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I was going to suggest the synonyms but do not have enough reputation (1250) to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the recommendation for the `mnemonic-seed` and `seed` synonym:

https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags/mnemonic-seed/synonyms